# Is there some route to delete on-hold questions quickly?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-hold

I came across a question, shortly after it was asked, which was "I wanted to know how to do something, found the way, so wanted to share it". Self-answered with a link.

Some irony that it was answered, before the self-answer, with the same link.

While the answers were coming in, I was involved in closing. The answers have some upvotes, so the answerers are benefiting even though the answers are (at the moment) net down.

Remembering a discussion from yesterday, I thought to flag for Very Low Quality on the question. However, I can't. The on-hold prevents that.

I don't want to custom-flag for moderator intervention unless that is thought to be a good idea. However, I want to do something to see the question safely gone. If the question-asker accepts his own answer, I believe it will no longer be auto-deleted in the near-ish future.

Oh, has a reopen vote as well.

I hesitate to link to the question, because the meta-effect will cause bad things to happ... Oh. That's what I want. Anyway, protocol is protocol, and anyone interested only needs a few seconds looking at my recent comments.

The deeper question is, should Very Low Quality really not be available on a question which is on hold (or closed)?

Comment: Well, starting a meta question about it would be one way but that doesn't scale very well.  It is closed, it cannot do a lot more damage, just give it time to get deleted.  There's a chat room where you can gather a posse, if necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant Yet if an answer gets accepted, it won't be deleted, was my concern. It was deliberately posted to self-answer, so an accept seemed a distinct possibility.

Comment: That does not stop it from getting delete votes.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, sorry, I thought you were referring to the automatic delete.

Answer (score 4):

20K users can vote to delete questions that score -3 or below immediately upon closure. They're expected to have enough experience to recognize posts that are exceptionally bad and unlikely to go anywhere good.

Spam or blatantly offensive posts can be deleted via flags at any time, closed or otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I did consider spam, but could find no link from the OP of the question to the tool. I did check. How do the 20K users get to see these? By luck, or some mechanism?

Comment: The question has gone by now, so looks like something worked for this one.

Comment: It's actually trivial to search for these, but there is also a 10K tool that... Mostly doesn't scale very well to SO's size, but still catches a good quanity.

Comment: Thanks again. 1k to go. That's about 3-6 months. Call it 6-8 weeks.

Comment: You can always hop in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room if you need advice, an extra pair of hands or just company if you're moderating posts, most of us don't bite @BillWoodger

Comment: @rene thanks. I do drop in from time to time. I need to again, but I'll also bear it in mind if I come across something like this again.